# Error: Unknown Column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

I receive an error that the column ls.amount is in field list when
I run the following query.

Can anyone help me diagnose the problem.

```
SELECT c.name, ic.keyword, COUNT(ic.keyword), SUM(ls.amount), ls.buyer FROM in_clicks AS ic
       INNER JOIN ads AS a ON ic.ad_id = a.id
       INNER JOIN ad_groups AS ag ON a.ad_group_id = ag.id
       INNER JOIN campaigns AS c ON ag.campaign_id = c.id;
       INNER JOIN leads AS l ON (ic.id = l.in_click_id)
       INNER JOIN lead_status AS ls ON (l.id = ls.lead_id)
WHERE ic.create_date LIKE '%2011-08-19%' AND ic.location NOT LIKE '%Littleton%' AND discriminator LIKE '%AUTO_POST%'
GROUP BY ic.keyword ORDER BY COUNT(ic.keyword) DESC
```

The exact error message is:

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'ls.amount' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Can we have the exact error please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but having `ic.keyword` and `COUNT(ic.keyword)` in the same query seems very suspicious to me...

Comment: @a1ex07 He's grouping by `ic.keyword` so he wants to know what keyword it is and how many occurrences there are.

Comment: @Vache : I believe in the original (not updated ) question there was `GROUP BY c.name`, not by `ic.keyword`, so it's why I posted my comment.

Comment: @gbn Maybe I didn't understand what you meant, but it definitely should work with `COUNT(ic.keyword)`. Example: http://www.ideone.com/RjFJ9

Comment: @vache: my mistake, I was thinking of MySQL's (dodgy) GROUP BY extensions. I checked on SQL Server which is strict with GROUP BY

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drop the semicolon (`;`) on line 4. I suspect that is ending you query before you can define the `ls` alias.

```
SELECT c.name,
       ic.keyword,
       COUNT(ic.keyword),
       SUM(ls.amount),
       ls.buyer
FROM   in_clicks AS ic
       INNER JOIN ads AS a
         ON ic.ad_id = a.id
       INNER JOIN ad_groups AS ag
         ON a.ad_group_id = ag.id
       INNER JOIN campaigns AS c
         ON ag.campaign_id = c.id
       INNER JOIN leads AS l
         ON ( ic.id = l.in_click_id )
       INNER JOIN lead_status AS ls
         ON ( l.id = ls.lead_id )
WHERE  ic.create_date LIKE '%2011-08-19%'
       AND ic.location NOT LIKE '%Littleton%'
       AND discriminator LIKE '%AUTO_POST%'
GROUP  BY ic.keyword
ORDER  BY COUNT(ic.keyword) DESC
```

Comment: doh, i can't believe I missed that. Thank You!

Comment: It happens to all of us from time to time :)